# Error while referring to matrix in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, matrix

I'm getting an error on this code trying to access to the data in a matrix. I also tried using two `for` loops but I got the exact same error

```
function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {

var answer = 0;

for(var i = 0 ; i < matrix[0].length; i++){ //gets horizontal axis

    var j = 0;

    while(matrix[j][i] !== 0 && j < matrix.length){
        answer += matrix[j][i];
        j++;
    }
}

return answer;
}

console.log(matrixElementsSum(
[[1,1,1,0], 
 [0,5,0,1], 
 [2,1,3,10]]));
```

The error is:

```
Deferred exception: matrix[j] is undefined
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. How can I fix this?

Comment: switch the order of the predicates: `matrix[j][i] !== 0 && j < matrix.length` (check `j` first)

Comment: Or just use a `for` loop instead of your `while` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {

  var answer = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) { //gets horizontal axis



      for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
          answer += matrix[i][j];

      }
  }

  return answer;
}

console.log(matrixElementsSum(
  [
      [1, 1, 1, 0],
      [0, 5, 0, 1],
      [2, 1, 3, 10]
  ]));
```

Answer (score 0):

[`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop can be used to make it easier (not supported in Internet Explorer) :

```js
function matrixElementsSum(matrix) 
{
  var answer = 0;

  for (var array of matrix)
    for (var number of array)
      answer += number;

  return answer;
}

console.log( matrixElementsSum( [[1,1,1,0], [0,5,0,1], [2,1,3,10]] ) );
```

For Internet Explorer, the for loop version can be transpiled on the  [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)